# Вводное слово или оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

В качестве возможной цели кампании была, в частности, озвучена цифра в два миллиона голосов в пользу...
Надо ли выделять запятыми В ЧАСТНОСТИ?

Comment: Подобное употребление слова *озвучить* встречается все чаще, но все равно раздражает. По строгим нормам должно считаться неверным, как минимум — сленговым.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**В качестве возможной цели кампании была, в частности, озвучена цифра в два миллиона голосов в пользу...**

В Вашем предложении *в частности* — это вводное слово, требующее обособления с двух сторон:
во-первых, его можно "изъять" из предложения без ущерба для смысла;
во-вторых, в предложении нет никаких присоединительных (обособленных) оборотов; в-третьих, оно разделяет составное сказуемое  *была озвучена*.

*Проблема была, в частности, озвучена на наблюдательном Совете новостроек при губернаторе Ленинградской области...*

*В докладе председателя (...) была, в частности, озвучена просьба к правительству...*

Освежить знания о вводных словах и сочетаниях можно [**здесь**](https://godliteratury.ru/events-post/zapyataya-stavit-nelzya-ne-stavit), особенности обособления *в частности* — на [**Грамоте**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8(,)).

Comment: Полностью согласна со всем сказанным, кроме того, что в частности - вводное сочетание, это вводное слово - форма предложного падежа с предлогом. Сочетание - два самостоятельных слова, служебные не считаются. Примеры сочетаний: нечего греха таить, без всякого сомнения и т.д.

Comment: Благодарю за поправку, я сомневалась (по поводу "слово" - "сочетание"). Сейчас внесу изменение в ответ.